# easy_install PIL fails

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt-get

I am trying to setup a dev environment on a new laptop, I am trying `sudo easy_install PIL` after seting up setuptools and python etc, I get this error. `Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

I have gcc and build_essentials installed, on Ubuntu Karmic. Full traceback is at http://dpaste.de/fHiW/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You must install the `python-dev`  package which includes the CPython header files needed to compile C extensions.